# renumbering image files to be contiguous in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, batch-rename

I have a directory with image files that follow a naming scheme and are not always contiguous. e.i:

```
IMG_33.jpg
IMG_34.jpg
IMG_35.jpg
IMG_223.jpg
IMG_224.jpg
IMG_225.jpg
IMG_226.jpg
IMG_446.jpg
```

I would like to rename them so they go something like this, *in the same order*:

```
0001.jpg
0002.jpg
0003.jpg
0004.jpg
0005.jpg
0006.jpg
0007.jpg
0008.jpg
```

So far this is what I came up, and while it does the four-digit padding, it doesn't sort by the number values in the filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash
X=1;
for i in *; do
  mv $i $(printf %04d.%s ${X%.*} ${i##*.})
  let X="$X+1"
done
```

result:

```
IMG_1009.JPG  0009.JPG
IMG_1010.JPG  0010.JPG
IMG_101.JPG  0011.JPG
IMG_102.JPG  0012.JPG
```

Comment: Take a look at `rename` command.

Comment: I did, but rename doesn't seem to be working giving me a "no such command" error.

Comment: You are going to need to do the padding *first* and then rename for contiguous-ness since the shell isn't going to glob the unpadded file names in the order you want (as you can see).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**:

Try this. If output is okay remove `echo`.

```
X=1; find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.jpg" -print0 | sort -z -n -t _ -k2 | while read -d $'\0' -r line; do echo mv "$line" "$(printf "%04d%s" $X .jpg)"; ((X++)); done
```

Comment: This seems like the right idea but it needs to happen *after* the first padding rename or the glob order will not be what he wants.

Comment: Do you mean I should do my script, and add this one afterwards? (I'm also very new to this, trying to figure it all out slowly)

Comment: +1, good answer. Doesn't matter for the files he lists, but I would also probably add `-print0` to `find`, `-d $'\0'` to `read`, and quote variables/command-substitution to catch some error cases.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks it works great. I have one question though. Does this in anyway change the order of the files as I notice the `sort`?

Comment: @JessieAltura: There are three possible ways: First: My answer sorts your files numerical. Second: If you want to keep the order `find` finds your files in your filesystem then remove `| sort -z -n -t _ -k2` from my answer. Third: Use your files in the way bash's globbing (with a *) sorts your files. In this case remove your complete `mv` line from **your** example and replace by `mv $i $(printf "%04d%s" $X .jpg)`. Prefix a `mv` with `echo ` for a dry-run.

Answer (score 1):

Using the super helpful `rename`. First, pads files with one digit to two digits; then pads files with two digits to three digits; etc.

```
rename IMG_ IMG_0 IMG_?.jpg
rename IMG_ IMG_0 IMG_??.jpg
rename IMG_ IMG_0 IMG_???.jpg
```

Then, your for-loop (or another similar one) that renames does the trick as the files are in both alphabetical and numerical order.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
 while read f1;do 
   echo $f1
   mv IMG_$f1 $f1
 done< <(ls | cut -d '_' -f 2 | sort -n)
```

thanks
Michael